# MATLAB How do I generate all possible square indexes

Tags: matlab, combinations, imaging

I have n amount of pixel values, I want to make a list of all possible combinations of squares that can be made with this list.

For example, if I have a list of 6 pixel values(n) all possible combinations are:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,6
2,3,4,5
2,3,4,6
3,4,5,6
```

How do i generate the above matrix using MATLAB using only n ?

Comment: You've tagged this with [processing], but this question is not about the Processing language.

Comment: So you want for a given N, all the combinations of 4 numbers without repetition? What do you mean by "squares"?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I keep noticing new users doing that tagging too.  On behalf of all of the n00bs, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
v = 1:6;
C = nchoosek(v,4)
```

Then `C` contains what you (probably) want.